# Subscribing SNS to SQS in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

Looking at this image :

[image]

The messages are really imporant hence I use a queue in the middle.
But now - On the right side SNS , I need to have multiple subscribers ( Lambdas).

But now, How can I subscribe the right side SNS to the SQS on the center ?

**Question:**

Is it possible to subscribe SNS to SQS ? ( meaning - passing the messages from SQS to an SNS)

Comment: please view the answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SNS is a topic, it does not subscribe to anything. It cannot receive data, it needs to be published to.

However, you can publish to it from an application code. For this, you can attach a consumer to your SQS in the middle. This could be a Java application or a simple lambda code.

Here are a few references for doing it in various languages.

1. [Java and .NET](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-tutorial-publish-message-to-topic.html#publish-message-to-topic-aws-java)
2. [Python](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sns.html#SNS.Client.publish)
3. [Node JS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/sns-examples-publishing-messages.html)

Comment: SQS can't have multiple lambdas ( it can but not all will run when event will rise)

Comment: @RoyiNamir, thanks for the comment. I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: plz delete the answer. as it doesnt answer the question

Answer (score 1):

First of all create a new Lambda function to send message to a SNS topic .
Refer this - https://github.com/aws-samples/serverless-app-examples/tree/master/python/step-functions-send-to-sns

And then you can configure your queue to trigger that Lambda function on receiving of payload.

Comment: thats not what ive asked. i want sns to listen to sqs

Comment: @RoyiNamir can you check my answer now?

Comment: @RoyiNamir This is what comes where you can configure SNS as an listener to SQS. Please revisit the AWS SQS console.

Comment: the menu you showed is you want that a queue will receive a message from SNS. I want the opposite. I want that my SNS will receive a message from SQS.

Comment: your answer is still wrong.  youre (AGAIN) subscribing to a situation where you send SNS to SQS. and I want the opposite.

Comment: @RoyiNamir my bad, please ignore above comments

Comment: @RoyiNamir Definitely dupe, but I would suggest you to at-least share your opinion on any answers given above (including Rajan's answers).